# Cycled Allocation

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to wrap my head around allocating and cycling a set of numbers to individuals who haven't been allocated a number yet.

For example, I have a table "numbers" with the following fixed numbers in them:

```
numbers
------------------
id       number
------------------
1        115552300
2        115552301
3        115552302
4        115552303
5        115552304
```

I then have a table "users" with the structure as followed:

```
users
----------------------------------------------------
id       name        surname        number
----------------------------------------------------
1        John        Doe            115552300
2        Jane        Doe            115552301
```

When creating a user, the next number in line should automatically be allocated to the new user. So if a new row is inserted, the row data may be as followed:

```
3        Bob         Dylan          115552302
```

Once the sequence hits the last number (Row 5), it should cycle back to the beginning to allocate the first number to the next inserted user.

In my mind, this seems something akin to a round robin algorithm; however I want to minimize resource usage in terms of not querying the database too many times in a single attempt to allocate the numbers in a cycled pattern.

I'm having difficulty trying to implement this concept.

I'm hoping someone might point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: What did you already try yourself?

Comment: You should keep track of the last allocated number somewhere. That should allow you do insert something with a single INSERT INTO ... SELECT... type insertion (But then you have to do a second query to update that number)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a little hard to tell what your actual use case is (why would you want to allocate a number twice?), but personally, I would try to use the database's auto increment to do this.

If you want to start at a specific number, you can tell (in this case mysql) it to start at a number.

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 115552300
```

then you can be sure that nothing is duplicated.

you seem to be using an ID and this 'number' field.  You should also consider using a UUID which would then give you a database-wide unique value.  [Docs here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid)